# add method to as3 class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

There is a Point (flash.geom.Point) class in as3
I want to add method to class Point (e.g. convertToStagePointMyMethod()) and I'd like to call this method by using

```
var a:Point=new Point();
a.convertToStagePointMyMethod()
```

What should I do in order to add this method to class Point? Is it possible without inheritance. I'd like to use it like "partial" classes in .NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a quick example using [prototype](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#prototype) :

```
Point.prototype.foo = function (arg:String):void{
    trace("foo called");//foo called
    trace("arg",arg);//this is a test
    trace("x",this.x);//7
    trace("y",this.y);//54
};

var p:Point = new Point(7,54);
p["foo"]("this is a test");
```

This is the only way to do this without extending a class.
Also note that the compiler will not compile in strict mode if you try to use `p.foo("test")`, that's why i wrote `p["foo"]("test")` in my example.

Comment: yeah I remember... the good old days... but it never really dawned on my that the prototype of a non-dynamic class could be altered and then accessed via the associative array style syntax - makes perfect sense since prototype is just an object. Very cool...

Comment: I have mixed feelings about using prototype...I feel like the way to go is to use inheritance or composition.

Comment: I'm with goliatone on this one. The whole prototype-style OOP system is a throwback to the old versions of ActionScript, and I personally wouldn't let anyone use this technique in one of my company's AS3 clients. You could subclass Point, of course, but you might also add a utility class to your project with a static function that operates on a Point. I would prefer either over the prototype route. On a side note, as much as I love the Moock book as a reference, I'd have hidden chapter 15 at the end of the book, and titled it "How not to write AS3" or "Typechecking is Overrated"

Comment: @goliatone @AdamSmith agree with you guys !

Comment: Yeah that's bad, that's the old AS2 ways of some sort of attempt at pseudo-OOP but it's actually counter-oop. Also the prototype isn't implemented until an instance of the class is processed in the virtual machine, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from using OXMO456's really cool example (never seen that before, really cool) you need to use either inheritance or composition. If the class were "dynamic" like the MovieClip class or the URLVariables class you wouldn't need to worry, but Point is not dynamic.

You can make your own dynamic classes by doing:

`dynamic public class MyClass {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Make your own point class

```
package 
{
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Jesse Nicholson
     */

    public class MyPoint extends Point 
    {
        public function MyPoint(positionX:Number, positionY:Number) {
            //Pass the constructor args to the super class, the Point class since it requires these params in it's constructor
            super(positionX, positionY);
        }

        public function convertToStagePointMyMethod():Number {
            //Do my calculations here
            var someNumber:Number = 10;
            return someNumer;

            //OR return a Point OR do whatever the hell you want here, you're the boss of your own point class
        }
    }

}
```

This is just plain the way you do things. When you have an existing class that you'd like to use but just add on to, extend it into a new class and do just that. This is a basic idea in object oriented programming and the "best practice" approach.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than extending a class, I usually create standalone utility functions, like this:

```
package com.example.utils
{
    public function doSomethingToPoint(p:Point):void
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Put it in a file called, doSomethingToPoint.as, and you're good to go. It works just like built-in package-level functions like [`flash.net.navigateToURL`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()). Just import and use the function directly.

```
import com.example.utils.doSomethingToPoint;

var p:Point = new Point();
doSomethingToPoint(p)
```

Alternatively, you could create a utility class with multiple related static functions, like this:

```
package com.example.utils
{
    public class PointUtil
    {
        public static function doSomethingToPoint(p:Point):void
        {
            //do something
        }

        //other functions here
    }
}
```

You'd use the class and its functions like this:

```
import com.example.utils.PointUtil;

PointUtil.doSomethingToPoint(p);
```

Personally, I prefer to create standalone functions so that my projects don't need to compile in extra static functions that aren't actually used anywhere, but everyone has their own preference.

Comment: Your second example is how I normally do this sort of thing in a larger project (when I know it's going to get used :-)